# When trying to read multiple inputs using a scanner, I can't make it read integers and chars

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here is the code

```
    public void promptUser(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Pick a coordinate [row col] or press [q] to quit.");
        int row = 0;
        int row = 0; 
        String line = scan.nextLine().trim();
        String[] contents = line.split(" ");
        if (contents[0] == "q"){
            isRunning = false;
            System.exit(0);
        }// if quit
        if (contents.length < 1 || contents.length > 2){
            System.out.print("Invalid Response. Try again.");
            promptUser();
        }// if wrong amount of input
        else {
            row = Integer.parseInt(contents[0]);
            col = Integer.parseInt(contents[1]);
        }// parse ints else
        if (inBounds(row, col) == true){
            if(!(board[row][col] == 'c'){
                click(row, col);
            }// has been clicked
        }// in bounds?
        else{
            System.out.print("Invalid response. Try again.");
            promptUser();
        }// else error
    }// promptUser method
```

and here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "q"    
     at    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)    
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)     
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)    
at Minesweeper.promptUser(Minesweeper.java:197)    
at Driver.main(Driver.java:12)
```

This method is meant to get input from the user, check it for errors. If it is correct, then it should exit the program if "q" is entered and "click" the coordinate if it is two integers inside the bounds that have not already been clicked. I can't enter 'q' without this error. I also get an `outOfBounds exception` with any integers entered. (Yes, this is homework, and I've searched long and hard, but haven't quite found out how to fix this.)
Any and all help is GREATLY appreciated.

Here is the inBounds method I use, and the initialize (where the board is initialized)

```
    public void initialize(){
    isRunning = true;
    board = new char[this.rows][this.cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){
            board[i][j] = 'e';

        }
    }
    mineBoard = new boolean[this.rows][this.cols];

    for (int i = 0; i < mineBoard.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < mineBoard[i].length; j++){
            mineBoard[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    Random bob = new Random();
    Random sally = new Random();
    for (int i = mines; i > 0; i--){
        int mineX = bob.nextInt(10);
        int mineY = sally.nextInt(10);
        if (mineBoard[mineX][mineY] == false){
            mineBoard[mineX][mineY] = true;
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

That's the initialize...
and here is the inBounds

```
    private boolean inBounds(int row, int col){
        if (row < 0 || row > board.length){
            return false;
        }
        if (col < 0 || col > board[0].length){
            return false;
        }else
            return true;
        }
```

is there anything else that would help? I fixed the problem with q, but I keep having problems with the out of bounds thing.

Comment: Note that the error message tells you exactly which line threw an exception, namely line 197 in the file "Minesweeper.java". Which line is this? When the user types 'q', should execution reach this line of code? I suspect not.

Comment: 197 is when it recalls promptUser(); is that not legal to re-call the method? I didn't want to redo the split and reassign everything because I didn't know if I could do that...

Comment: Calling `promptUser();` again is fine. This is called recursion. I see that others have commented about this, so I won't go any detail. Besides, that's not the point. My point is this: if the user types 'q', should your program's execution reach line 197? I think the answer is no because a 'q' means that the user is finished and you want to exit the program, correct? If this is so, then the problem must be somewhere before line 197, most likely in an if statement.

Comment: Someone else has pointed out the exact problem. I'm just trying to illustrate the thought process I would use to find where the problem occurs. I believe in the dictum about teaching a man (or woman) to fish rather than giving him (or her) a fish.

Comment: Can you try http://commons.apache.org/cli/ to get inputs from user.

Answer (score 4):

Use `contents[0].equals("q")`. Otherwise, the equality will fail, hence your `NumberFormatException` later on. You can learn more about this [common mistake](http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/).

Essentially what is happening is that you have two `String`s -- the literal `"q"`, and the `split` result from the user input. While both may be *semantically* equivalent (i.e. `contents[0].equals("q")`), they more than likely will not be *identical*, since one is constructed from user input. Since they aren't *identical* objects, `==` will fail, causing your code flow to continue on. It will attempt to invoke `Integer.parseInt("q")` -- which  fails with a `NumberFormatException` because it's an invalid number.

Your "*outOfBounds exception*" is most likely `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which is likely caused by your `row`, `col` being too big for your array (in fact, they're outside of it -- hence, out of bounds). To verify this, you'll need to show more code.

---

Additionally, you don't need to write `if (inBounds(row, col) == true)`. Any `boolean` expression `b` will satisfy the tautology `b <=> b == true`, i.e. its merely the identity. You can just write the more concise and simple `if (inBounds(row, col))`.

Furthermore, you should avoid the recursion you have right now. In the case of repeated invalid response, a `StackOverflowException` can be triggered. Be careful when using unbound recursion as such, as the Java call stack *is* bounded.

Comment: The array is a [10][10] array, so 0 and 2 are inside, which is why I don't understand the out of bounds... Sorry, I'm new to this, what do you mean by recursion? Also, how can I avoid it?

Comment: @Gwyen show more code to demonstrate. We can't figure it out without you giving us a more detailed report of the exception (maybe give us the trace?) as well as more code to look through. If you can create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) with minimal code to exhibit the behavior, that would be *awesome*.

Comment: @Gwyen recursion here is your repeated calling of `promptUser` from within `promptUser` to simulate a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is experienced quite commonly when programmers are starting out. Basically, the == operator compares the references of the two object you are comparing. For Strings (and other objects) this is almost always false. In your case, you should use something like:

```
contents[0].equals("q")
```

This will call the equals method of the String class, which will correctly compare the content of the two Strings.